# Transferring wp8 project to different computer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

My old computer broke down and I have my project folders zipped and backed up in the cloud. I have downloaded them to the new computer and placed them in the 'Projects' folder in VS 2012 for WP. I am able to open the solution file but building the app is throwing read errors and is showing me the path on the old broken computer. Please advice on the right method on transferring a windows phone project across computers.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your .csproj files in Notepad and manually fix any paths you find.  You may also need to do this in your .sln file.